# arabtex: how to write two consecutive identical Farsi characters without adding Arabic shadda

Tags: arabic, persian, arabtex

I'm using the `arabtex` to write som Persian/Farsi words in Latex. When I'm trying to write two consecutive `ن` like `نن` in a word like `کنند`, arabtex adds shadda since it's part of its commands by default (`xx` for ARABIC SHADDA, reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX). This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
{\setfarsi\novocalize \<rA.dy knndh >}
\end{document}
```

That results in:

[image]

While my desired output is `راضی کننده`. I wonder how I can get my desired output?

Answer (score 2):

The way to go with `arabtex` is to use the 'pipe' character (`|`) which prevents the *šadda* from being generated, like so:—

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
{\setfarsi\novocalize \<rA.dy kn|ndh >}
\end{document}
```

See the [documentation](http://129.69.218.213/arabtex/doc/arabdoc.pdf) of `arabtex` on p. 20 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `i` between the characters solved my problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
{\setfarsi\novocalize \<rA.dy knindh >}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, instead of PDFLaTeX, you can type in Unicode with whatever input method and text editor you prefer.

Here’s a template you can tweak.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular, nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\babelfont{rm}
          [Scale=1.0]{Libertinus Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          {Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          {Libertinus Mono}

\babelprovide[import=fa, main]{persian} % You can call it farsi instead, if you prefer.

\babelfont[persian]{rm}
          [Language=Default]{Amiri}
% Define \babelfont[persian]{sf} here if needed.
\babelfont[persian]{tt}
          {ALM Fixed}

\begin{document}
کنند
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Since I need this for an arXiv submission and arXiv apparently has an issue with `babel`, I had to use the `arabtex` instead.

Comment: @Pedram You might have a look at `farsitex`, then.